# Is 'Sierra Online' somehow related to 'Valve Studios'?

Tags: gaming-history

Is there any connection between the two developer studios: 'Sierra Online' and 'Valve Studios'?

Comment: What made you ask this question? Why do you want to know? Did you look into it?

Comment: I looked for 15 years and still no clear answer. An old 1987 video game published by Sierra made me want to know this, because I have heard it later turned into Valve

Comment: Where did you look then?!! I remember very fondly the logos of both Sierra and Valve from the Half-Life demo (I think Sierra Online had a popup during installation or so), and the full thing and its expansions after that. Good times!

Comment: @Joachim the correct answer is that 'Sierra 'is not a developer, then, but a publisher

Answer (score 5):

Valve developed the game Half-Life, which was [published](https://web.archive.org/web/20041211055313/https://www.gamespot.com/features/halflife_final/part24.html/) in 1998 by Sierra On-Line. In 2002, Sierra On-Line officially changed their named to Sierra Entertainment, Inc. After Sierra was acquired by Vivendi Universal Games, and later Activision Blizzard, Valve was involved in legal disputes with Sierra's parent companies:

- https://www.gamespot.com/articles/valve-vs-vivendi-universal-dogfight-heats-up-in-us-district-court/1100-6107712/
- https://www.leagle.com/decision/infco20100730214

Comment: let me question more: Is 'Sierra Entertainment' related to 'Sierra On-line'?

Comment: That is literally in the opening statement of the [Sierra Entertainment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierra_Entertainment) wikipedia article: *"Sierra Entertainment, Inc. (formerly On-Line Systems and Sierra On-Line, Inc.)"*